# Проблема с выделением памяти в php

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

Не могу разобраться со следующей проблемой. Требуется выгрузить из базы данных большую таблицу в 40к строк, но столкнулся с проблемой:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) line 58

Выгрузить нужно в html, таблица должна быть отображена и потом должна быть возможность сохранения в Excel. Для отображения использую Vue + axios.

Использование ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') помогло, но я всё таки думаю, что я что то не так делаю с памятью, прошу помощи более опытных людей. Ошибка проявляется на цикле while

Пример кода:

```
$c = oci_parse($oci_connect, $query);
$data = array();
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
json_encode($data, true);

$json = json_decode($data, true);
/*$id1 = $json['sel1'];
$id2 = $json['sel2'];
$id3 = $json['sel_ch'];*/

$id1 = null;
$id2 = 201906;
$id3 = 143729749;

oci_bind_by_name($c, ':filial_ID', $id1);
oci_bind_by_name($c, ':period', $id2);
oci_bind_by_name($c, ':sale_channel_id', $id3);

oci_execute($c);

/*if ( ! oci_execute($c)) {
    $oci_error = oci_error($c);
    die($oci_error["message"]);
}*/


//ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$stack = array();
echo memory_get_usage();
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($c)) != false) {
    array_push($stack, $row);
    //echo json_encode($row, true);
    /*print_r ($row);
    unset($row);*/
}

echo json_encode($stack, true);

echo memory_get_usage();

/*oci_fetch_all($c, $res);

echo json_encode($res, true);*/

oci_close($oci_connect);
```

Comment: на кой вам показывать сразу 40к строк. покажите 200строк, и по мере прокрутки подгружайте дальнейшие. 40к строк с версткой это и объем сам по себе не маленький,  дак и браузер мягко говоря в шоке будет от такой таблицы.

Comment: зы: можно вообще писать а-ля `$stack = []` и `$stack[] = $row`, если что.

Comment: у вас какой версии оракл то? может прям с сервера JSON получить, а не формировать его в пхп?

Comment: Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Тогда вопрос, как сделать так, что подгружалось по 200 строк, при этом работало с axios и Vue

Comment: гугли постраниыный вывод пхп. будешь удивлен количеством результатов. ну или бесконечная прогрутка, если непонятно, как из одного сделать другое

Answer (score 2):

Данные занимают память, если данных много, они занимают много памяти. Как получить большой объём данных, не загружая их все в оперативную память? Можно выводить (в файл, стандартный вывод, в html-таблицу в браузере пользователя) данные кусками. Загрузить, скажем, 1000 строк, вывести, снова 1000 и так далее, пока не получится 40к.

В конкретно вашем случае вы взаимодействуете со своим пхп-скриптом по HTTP и можно отправить один запрос на 1000 строк, следующий запрос на следующую 1000! Это и называют пагинацией (постраничным выводом).

В результате можно напихать пользователю в браузер все 40к строк. И тут вы удивитесь. Теперь память начнёт жрать браузер! Кроме того ни один нормальный человек не сможет изучать все 40к строк и делать какие-то полезные выводы. Выходит, что и в браузер не надо совать все 40к, а надо нарисовать пользователю кнопочку "Показть ещё" или список страниц.

Если вы решите создать excel-файл из 40к строк, то заметите что и экселю может стать плоховато. Но если вы всё-таки решитесь, то вам опять-таки не надо вытаскивать сразу 40к, пишите файл строка за строкой (csv, например) и не сохраняйте сроки из базы в массив.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `$stack` занимает слишком много места в памяти. Попробуйте вывести данные без предварительной записи в массив. Как-то так:

```php
ob_start();

echo "[";
$isFirst = true;
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($c)) != false) {
    echo ($isFirst ? '' : ','), json_encode($row, true);
    $isFirst = false;
}
echo "]";

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: по сути хоть и костыль, но проблему с лимитом решит, скорее всего :)

Comment: @teran, да самому не очень нравится несколько `echo`. Или у этого способа еще какие-то проблемы есть?

Comment: пробел не нужен после запятой между объектами. Вопрос в том, нужны ли реально все эти данные пользователю. Одно дело автор упомянул экспорт в эксель, тут нужен (но и кодировать в json не надо). А вот нужно ли ему все сразу для показа в браузере - сомнительно. Скорее всего выборка всего набора данных сразу - лишняя трата ресурсов, которая выльется в задержку для пользователя.

Comment: Я тоже пробовал выводить в цикле, но тут появляется другая проблема, не работает axios, соответственно я не могу получить эти данные в html. Данные нужны все, я понимаю, что их загрузка займёт время и большое кол во ресурсов.

Comment: поправил ответ. Попробуйте обрамить вывод при помощи `ob_start() ... ob_end_flush()`

Comment: при чем здесь "**несколько echo**"?! Какая разница, сколько операторов используется? Проблема в том, что вместо использования специально предназначенной функции, данные здесь формируются  на коленке, что приведет к проблемам при изменении данных или формата

Comment: @Ипатьев а как бы вы решили подобную проблему не прибегая к постраничному выводу?

Comment: единственный осмысленный ответ дал teran - постраничный вывод. фигачить джейсон руками выглядит хорошим решением здесь и сейчас, в типичной похапешной парадигме "фигак-фигак и в продакшен". А у кого будет голова болеть в будущем, когда эти сопли на ровном месте поломаются - это нам до барабана.

Comment: @Ипатьев, вы абсолютно правы насчёт постраничного вывода. Как думаете, вы бы с радостью поддерживали решение постраничного вывода в PHP и JS от человека, который только начал и черпает вдохновение на php.net? (автору: бро, у вас всё ок, многие начинали свой путь с php.net)

Comment: Вся строка будет копится в буфере до `ob_end_flush` и это тоже будет занимать память. В json скорее всего больше чем массив.

Comment: @Ипатьев, @teran не согласен, что `по сути хоть и костыль`, `хорошим решением здесь и сейчас`. Данных много, в памяти они не помещаются. Для таких вещей нужно использовать потоки. Нативных средств в пыхе для JSON нет (но есть для XML типа XML reader и writer). По этой причине это решение мне нравится. А если хочется более правильно, вот есть пакетик: https://packagist.org/packages/bcncommerce/json-stream

Comment: @sneas поправил как вы предложили, всё так же не работает, если просто php скрипт запустить, то конечно я получаю закодированные JSON данные, но вот в HTML я получаю этот массив нулевым. Я думаю, здесь проблема именно в axios, ну или я что то не так делаю

Comment: Даже если реализовывать постраничный вывод, то можно хотя бы пару примеров этой реализации?